# How to index specific elements of a linear model summary output - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, statistics, regression

I have the following linear model output.

I want to index a particular value, printing only the R-squared value (0.028) but am not sure how to do this.

Would be so grateful for a helping hand!

```
resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary

OLS Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  distance    R-squared:  0.028
Model:  OLS Adj. R-squared: 0.016
Method: Least Squares   F-statistic:    2.338
Date:   Fri, 18 Nov 2022    Prob (F-statistic): 0.00773
Time:   10:06:14    Log-Likelihood: -1274.1
No. Observations:   907 AIC:    2572.
Df Residuals:   895 BIC:    2630.
Df Model:   11      
Covariance Type:    nonrobust
```

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by adding the following code:

```
newerresults = resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary.tables[0]
newerdata = pd.DataFrame(newerresults)
print(newerdata.iloc[0,3])
```

Convert to table - then to dataframe - then index
:)